# jQuery acts different in IE than Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have a form that contains uploading a file. I created a jQuery function to validated and display the file size whens selecting a file. When the user browsers and select a file In Google Chrome, the size appears immediately. However, In IE the file size appears when submitting the form meaning if all the form fields are valid and the user click submit button the file size appears for like 1 second then I direct the user to successful page.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
(function ($, W, D) {
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL = {
        setupFormValidation: function () {
            $("#addMeeting-form").validate({
                errorElement: 'div',
                rules: {
                    record: {
                        required: true,
                        accept: "doc|docx|pdf",
                        checkRecordSize: true
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });

            jQuery.validator.addMethod('checkRecordSize', function () {
                var iSize = ($("#recordToUpload")[0].files[0].size / 1024);
                if (iSize / 1024 > 1) {
                    if (((iSize / 1024) / 1024) > 1) {
                        iSize = (Math.round(((iSize / 1024) / 1024) * 100) / 100);
                        $("#lblSize").html(iSize + " GB");
                    } else {
                        iSize = (Math.round((iSize / 1024) * 100) / 100);
                        $("#lblSize").html(iSize + " MB");
                    }
                } else {
                    iSize = (Math.round(iSize * 100) / 100);
                    $("#lblSize").html(iSize + " KB");
                }
                return (iSize < 4294967295); // 4GB is 4,294,967,295 bytes
            }, "Your file size exceeded 4GB");
        }
    };
    $(D).ready(function ($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

How to make the behavior of the size of the file in IE as in Google Chrome ? 
My IE version is 11 But I set it to 10 mode.

Answer (score 0):

Old version of Internet Explorer has not implemented the API for file uploads and it can not access the file properties. It first upload the file to the server and then access its properties.

For this reason first send the image to the server and then checks the size. In modern browsers  they have implemented  API for uploading files and  they can access  the properties of the file to upload before sending it to the server.

In the latest versions of Intertet explorer you don´t  have to have problems for it.

Comment: Even thought I change it to 11 still the size appears after I click submit ):

Comment: do you have in any meta tag something like this:
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"> ?

Comment: I was having the same but IE=10. Now removing that dose not help at all, it makes all my jquery validation off meaning the form is submitted and I didn't even fill one failed.

Comment: I decide to use IE=edge to make my jQuery works great But the size of the file still the same (appearing after submit) .. this is killing me I searched so much >_<